# How to assign all the files listed in a directory to a filelist using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, directory

I have a requirement to compare files available in a directory and the below code is working fine only when I mention the file names (file1 file2 file3 file4) individually to the filelist

```
#!/bin/bash

filelist=(file1 file2 file3 file4) 


# Outer for loop
for (( i=0; i<${#filelist[@]} ; i+=1 )) ; do
    # Inner for loop
    for (( j=i+1; j<${#filelist[@]} ; j+=1 )) ; do

    echo "Unique between ${filelist[i]}" "${filelist[j]}" > unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    echo -e "Unique in ${filelist[i]}"  >> unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    # Will produce unique lines in 'file i' when comparing 'file i' and 'file j'
    join -v 1 <(sort ${filelist[i]}) <(sort ${filelist[j]}) >> unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    echo -e "Unique in  ${filelist[j]}" >> unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    # Will produce unique lines in 'file j' when comparing 'file i' and 'file j'
    join -v 2 <(sort ${filelist[i]}) <(sort ${filelist[j]}) >> unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    done

done
```

But what exactly I want is to assign the files that are available in a directory to the filelist directly. Any working solution please?

Comment: Answer you have accepted won't give correct result if filenames have space. You can verify it. Only my answer is correct.

Comment: Verification : mkdir -p /tmp/test && cd test && touch List\ s && filelist=($(/bin/ls)) && shuf -e "${filelist[@]}"

Comment: You will see 2 files for accepted answer using ls and 1 for me. Latter is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
 #!/bin/bash

#set basedir to . if no dir is given
if [ -n "$1" ]; then basedir=$1; else basedir=$(pwd);fi

filelist=($(/bin/ls $basedir))
# Outer for loop
for (( i=0; i<${#filelist[@]} ; i+=1 )) ; do
    # Inner for loop
    for (( j=i+1; j<${#filelist[@]} ; j+=1 )) ; do

    echo "Unique between $basedir/${filelist[i]}" "$basedir${filelist[j]}" > $basedir/unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    echo -e "Unique in $basedir/${filelist[i]}"  >> $basedir/unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    # Will produce unique lines in 'file i' when comparing 'file i' and 'file j'
    join -v 1 <(sort $basedir/${filelist[i]}) <(sort $basedir/${filelist[j]}) >> $basedir/unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    echo -e "Unique in  $basedir/${filelist[j]}" >> $basedir/unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    # Will produce unique lines in 'file j' when comparing 'file i' and 'file j'
    join -v 2 <(sort $basedir/${filelist[i]}) <(sort $basedir/${filelist[j]}) >> $basedir/unique${filelist[i]}${filelist[j]}.txt

    done

done
```

The folder should not contain directories. But its working ether.
The unique files will created in folder given to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script work on current directory, use this:-

```
filelist=(*)
```

It will get all files in directory via globbing. Don't use `ls`.

All the answers here except mine are wrong. (Out of first 3 till now.)

Simple test:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test && cd test && touch List\ s && filelist=($(/bin/ls)) && shuf -e "${filelist[@]} | wc -l

mkdir -p /tmp/test && cd test && touch List\ s && filelist=(*) && shuf -e "${filelist[@]} | wc -l
```

It should give 1 in both cases. But it won't.

Comment: Do you know why should not I use ls?

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy If you are using ls it won't give correct result if there are spaces and such.

Answer (score 0):

If your running the script from current directory you can use following code

```
fileArr=( $(ls) ) #list the files and store in array
echo ${#fileArr[@]}
echo "${fileArr[@]}"
for i in "${fileArr[@]}"
do
    echo $i #read the fil
done
```

Edited : Without using ls

```
shopt -s nullglob
fileArr1=(*)
fileArr2=(file*)
fileArr3=(dir/*)

echo ${#fileArr1[@]}
echo "${fileArr1[@]}"
for i in "${fileArr1[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done    

echo ${#fileArr2[@]}
echo "${fileArr2[@]}"
for i in "${fileArr2[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done    

echo ${#fileArr3[@]}
echo "${fileArr3[@]}"
for i in "${fileArr3[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```